# Unable to configure SAML2 Web SSO Configuration under Service Providers in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, saml, apim

I am trying to implement SAML Extension Grant by following the instructions in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/APISecurity/OAuth2/GrantTypes/saml-extension-grant/ but got a blank screen when I tried to configure the service provider:

1. Sign into the Management Console
2. Select **Service Providers > Add**
3. After I registered the service provider, click **Inbound Authentication Configuration > SAML2 Web SSO Configuration**.
4. Click **Configure**. A blank screen appears.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a similar issue reported in APIM 3.0.0. Please refer to the git issue [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7124)

Inbound SAML2 Web SSO Authentication will not work in APIM OOTB as the relevant Identity feature is not available. If you need to use this, you need to use WSO2 IS or WSO2 IS-KM.